# Is it possible in emacs intero-mode to start a session on a remote host

Tags: haskell, emacs, intero

I have:

- mac laptop (running emacs, haskell-mode intero installed)
- linux cluster (don't have root access)

  - can mount home partition using sshfs
  - stack installed and running in user mode

Would it be possible to let the stack and ghci and other backend processes execute on the cluster from my mac ?

Thanks in advance,